# Multiple TemplateIds not working in Sitecore's Advanced Database Crawler

Tags: sitecore

I have a "Featured" widget to lead visitors to items I want to feature on certain pages. So I'm trying to get Alex Shyba's Advanced Database Crawler for Sitecore to return all the items that refer to the context item. If I put in one template ID, it works fine. But if I pipe delimit the two templates, I never get a result. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
var searchParam = new MultiFieldSearchParam()
{
    Database = Sitecore.Context.Database.Name,
    Language = Sitecore.Context.Language.Name,
    TemplateIds = "{E5B41848-3C07-4F17-84A5-C2C29AD43CAE}|{0C2E35D7-C4C9-478B-B4AB-DE8C2A00908B}"
};            
var refinements = new List<MultiFieldSearchParam.Refinement>();
refinements.Add(new MultiFieldSearchParam.Refinement("pages", contextItemGUID));
searchParam.Refinements = refinements;

var runner = new QueryRunner("web");
foreach (var skinnyItem in runner.GetItems(searchParam))
{
    yield return skinnyItem.GetItem();
}
```

Again, if I make that `TemplateIds` a single GUID (either one), it works as expected, but just returning, obviously, items of the specified template.

Comment: Converting to ShortIDs didn't help either. Same results: 1 Template ID and it's just fine.

Comment: That's a bug. Refer to my solution in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715982/can-we-assign-more-then-one-template-id-in-templateid-like-we-do-in-relatedid

Answer (score 0):

As Mark notes, it's a bug in the ADC. Our solution was to refactor the ApplyTemplateFilter method as follows:

```cs
protected void ApplyTemplateFilter(CombinedQuery query, string templateIds, QueryOccurance occurance)
{
    ApplyIdFilter(query, BuiltinFields.Template, templateIds, occurance);
}
```

Comment: in which name space ApplyIdFilter in?