# Sitecore Search Template Query

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, content-management-system, sitecore

I want to query the template of content items in Sitecore so that it returns results if the template of the item matches any of the TemplateID's included in the `templates` variable. The `templates` variable contains a pipe separated list of TemplateID's to search for on the content item.

I have tried a few different methods but nothing has provided the result that I am looking for. The below is one such example, I have also tried separating out each template using a split on the templates string and running a foreach loop over the below.

```
var multiSearchParam = new MultiFieldSearchParam 
{
    Database = dbName,
    InnerCondition = QueryOccurance.Should
};
multiSearchParam.TemplateIds = templates;
parameters.Add(multiSearchParam);
```

I feel as though there is a problem with the conditions I am using.... When I run this with just a single template ID it works like a charm so it seems to be an issue with querying multiple templates.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809520/multiple-templateids-not-working-in-sitecores-advanced-database-crawler and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9715982/can-we-assign-more-then-one-template-id-in-templateid-like-we-do-in-relatedid ?

Comment: I voted to close, thanks for the links!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Sitecore ContentSearch, this is how i solve it:

```
 Expression<Func<SearchResultItem, bool>> predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.TemplateName.Equals("News"));
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.TemplateName.Equals("Page"));

            IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> results = _searchContext
                .GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                .Where(predicate);
```